# Paramiko: Creating a PKey from a public key string

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I'm trying to use the SSH protocol at a low level (i.e. I don't want to start a shell or anything, I just want to pass data). Thus, I am using Paramiko's [`Transport`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html) class directly.

I've got the server side done, but now I'm hitting a wall over something silly. For the client to connect to the server, the `Transport`'s [`connect` method](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html#connect) takes as two [`PKey`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html) objects as argument: The private key of the client (`pkey`), and the public key of the server (`hostkey`).

The [`PKey`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html) class is described as "Base class for public keys". Yet the problem is that I can't figure out how to create such a [`PKey`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html) object out of just an ssh public key (i.e. a string `ssh-whatever AAblablabla`). It has methods for building such an object out of a private key, but obviously I don't want the client to know the server's private key.

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple, but I can't find info on doing that on the web; most tutorials out there use the higher-level [`SSHClient` class](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html) which loads the system's `known_hosts` keys.

Comment: To follow up on my suggestion that passing in data to PKey would work (which it does not), PKey does not even implement the constructor and RSAKey does not seem to accept the data parameter as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had to solve this problem again in another context that wasn't just for key comparison (it was for signature checking). Here's the proper way to do it. In retrospect it was pretty simple, but hardly documented at all.

```
# For a public key "ssh-rsa AAblablabla...":
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.b64decode('AAblablabla...'))
key.verify_ssh_sig(..., ...)
```

Comment: anyone can expand on this solution? i dont understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Worked around it by calling the individual methods described in the [`connect` method documentation](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html#connect):

```
clientPrivateKey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(...)
transport = paramiko.Transport(...)
knownServerKey = 'ssh-rsa AAblablabla'.split(' ', 3)
transport.start_client()
serverKey = transport.get_remote_server_key()
if serverKey.get_name() == knownServerKey[0] and serverKey.get_base64() == knownServerKey[1]:
    # Valid key
    transport.auth_publickey('username', clientPrivateKey)
    channel = transport.open_channel('...')
else:
    # Invalid key
```

This is more or less [what the `connect` method does anyway](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.transport-pysrc.html#Transport.connect-def).

I am still open to better/shorter suggestions though. As it stands, the `hostkey` parameter of the `connect` method seems unusable.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto the solution provided for the Transport Client. Here is my solution for adding a string public key to the SSH Client:

```
my_pub_key = "xx.xx.xx.xx ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 mlzdHAyNT....."
my_host = my_pub_key.split(' ')[0]
password = 'myFavortitePassword'
username = 'myUsername'

ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()

host_key_policy = paramiko.MissingHostKeyPolicy()
host_key_policy.missing_host_key(ssh_client, my_host, my_pub_key)

ssh_client.connect(hostname= my_host
                            ,username=username
                            ,password=password
                            ,port=22
                            ,look_for_keys=False)
```